# change order of rows in MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql

i have this PHP code that lists rows in a table:

```
$sql="SELECT * from pages order by menu_order ASC ";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        echo '<a href="edit_page.php?pagename='.$result["pagename"].'">'.$result["title"].'</a> - <a href="edit_page.php?do=up&page_order='.$result["menu_order"].'&seq='.$result["sequence"].'">Move Up</a> | <a href="edit_page.php?do=down&page_order='.$result["menu_order"].'&seq='.$result["sequence"].'">Move Down</a><br><br>';
    }
```

they have up and down links to change the order

that uses this code:

```
$page_order = $_GET['page_order'];
if ($_GET['do'] == 'up')
{
    $sql="UPDATE pages SET menu_order = '$page_order' +1 WHERE sequence != '".$_GET["seq"]."' AND menu_order < '$page_order' ";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());

    $sql="UPDATE pages SET menu_order = menu_order -1 WHERE sequence = '".$_GET["seq"]."' ";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
}
elseif($_GET['do'] == 'down')
{
    $sql="UPDATE pages SET menu_order = '$page_order' -1 WHERE sequence != '".$_GET["seq"]."' ";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());

    $sql="UPDATE pages SET menu_order = menu_order +1 WHERE sequence = '".$_GET["seq"]."' ";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

but its not working - it changes the numbers randomly and, like changes them all to 0 or minus numbers

whats the best way to do this correctly?

EDIT: New Code...

i have tried this code but it doesnt work quite right - if i move the bottom row right up the top it changes the number -1 each time but ends up duplicate order numbers?

```
$current = $_GET["menu_order"];
$prev = $current-1;
$next = $current;

if($_GET['do'] == 'up')
{
    $sql2="UPDATE pages SET menu_order = '".($prev)."' WHERE sequence = '".$_GET["seq"]."' ";
    echo $sql2.'<br>';
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());

    $sql2="UPDATE pages SET menu_order = '".($next)."' WHERE sequence = '".($_GET["seq"]-1)."' ";
    echo $sql2;
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
}
elseif($_GET['do'] == 'down')
{
    $sql2="UPDATE pages SET menu_order = '".($next)."' WHERE sequence = '".$_GET["seq"]."' ";
    echo $sql2.'<br>';
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());

    $sql2="UPDATE pages SET menu_order = '".($prev)."' WHERE sequence = '".($_GET["seq"]+1)."' ";
    echo $sql2;
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: please provide the desired result set and a sqlfiddle

Comment: It's hard to say since I don't know what the "sequence" column means in your setup. It also seems premature to be assigning "$prev" and "$next" values at the top, because this will be different depending on whether or not $_GET['do'] is "up" or "down". Have you tried using the code I posted (modifying it for your schema of course)? It's working code that I use in my project to do the same thing.

Comment: sequence is just an id column, a unique number for each. i have tried using your code however, its PDO which i have never used before and i cannot get my head round it

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup in one of my applications where I have a list of pages on a site, and the user can click up/down arrows to re-order the pages.  When they click the up/down arrows, it sends the page_id that they clicked on, and then the either "up" or "down.

I'm using PDO, so my formatting will look a little different than yours.  Also, the pages on my site can be layered (i.e. drop-down navigation), so they also have parent IDs.  When I change the order of them, I want them to change the order within the parent's children, not within the entire set of pages.  If what you're trying to order is flat, you can remove some of this.

The first step is to get the parent_id of the page that we want to move:

```
$parent_query  = "SELECT parent_id FROM page WHERE page_id = :page_id";
$parent_result = $db_mysql->prepare( $parent_query );
$parent_result->execute( array(
    ":page_id" => $_GET['page_id']
));

$parent_row = $parent_result->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
```

Next we get the display order of the current page:

```
$page_query = "SELECT disp_order FROM page WHERE page_id   = :page_id AND parent_id = :parent_id";
$page_result = $db_mysql->prepare( $page_query );
$page_result->execute( array(
    ":page_id"   => $_GET['page_id'],
    ":parent_id" => $parent_row['parent_id']
));

$page_row = $page_result->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now we're going to get the display order of the page that we're swapping with.  If we clicked to move down, then we'll get the page_id and disp_order of the next page.  If we clicked to move up, hen we'll get the page_id and disp_order of the previous page:

```
$swappage_query = "SELECT page_id, disp_order FROM page WHERE disp_order = :disp_order AND parent_id  = :parent_id";
$swappage_result = $db_mysql->prepare( $swappage_query );

if( $_GET['move'] == "up" ) {
    $swappage_result->execute( array(
        ":disp_order" => $page_row['disp_order'] - 1,
        ":parent_id"  => $parent_row['parent_id']
    ));
} else {
    $swappage_result->execute( array(
        ":disp_order" => $page_row['disp_order'] + 1,
        ":parent_id"  => $parent_row['parent_id']
    ));
}

$swappage_row = $swappage_result->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
```

Finally, we're going to execute the swap by changing the display order of both the page we clicked on and the page next to it that we're swapping with:

```
$neworder_query = "UPDATE page SET disp_order = :disp_order WHERE page_id = :page_id";

$neworder_result = $db_mysql->prepare( $neworder_query );
$neworder_result->execute( array(
    ":disp_order" => $swappage_row['disp_order'],
    ":page_id"    => $_GET['page_id']
));

$neworder_result->execute( array(
    ":disp_order" => $page_row['disp_order'],
    ":page_id"    => $swappage_row['page_id']
));
```

What I'm doing here is this:

- Get the parent_id of the page we clicked on so that we only move pages around within the parent_id, not other parent's children.  If what you're ordering is a flat list without layering, you can skip this step.
- Get the display order of the current page.  Since the display orders are stored sequentially, such as 1, 2, 3, and so on, knowing the display order of the current page will tell me which page I need to swap with.  If the current page has a display order of 3, then the page to swap with is either 2 or 4 depending on whether I clicked on "up" or "down", respectively.
- Get page_id for the page we're going to swap with.  If we clicked "up", then it's the current page's disp_order - 1.  If we clicked "down", then it's the current page's disp_order + 1.
- Execute the swap, which means to change the current one to disp_order + 1 or disp_order - 1 depending on "up" or "down, and then do the opposite with the page we're swapping with.

Comment: hmm - ok il have to look into it a bit more as ive never used PDO before, unless you have an example not using PDO?

Comment: Better start using PDO now as `mysql_` functions are [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)

Comment: @charlie: PDO is recommended, but not required to accomplish this task. I only mentioned it in my response because I'm using PDO and you're not, so I wanted to make sure the formatting differences were clear.